# Coldfusion, 5 forms submit to iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, iframe, coldfusion

I have 5 forms in coldfusion that submit to one iFrame, and that iFrame calls another coldfusion page. My forms and iFrame are working fine. My problem is that I need to wait one form finish submitting to call submit of the another form.

```
$("#form1").attr('action', 'uploadPicturesVideos.cfm');
$("#form1").attr('target', 'uploadIframe');
$("#form1").submit();

$("#form2").attr('action', 'uploadPicturesVideos.cfm');
$("#form2").attr('target', 'uploadIframe');
$("#form2").submit();

$("#form3").attr('action', 'uploadPicturesVideos.cfm');
$("#form3").attr('target', 'uploadIframe');
$("#form3").submit();

$("#form4").attr('action', 'uploadPicturesVideos.cfm');
$("#form4").attr('target', 'uploadIframe');
$("#form4").submit();

$("#form5").attr('action', 'uploadPicturesVideos.cfm');
$("#form5").attr('target', 'uploadIframe');
$("#form5").submit();
```

My question is how can I wait form1 finish submitting to start submitting form2... form3... form4... form5

Thanks

Comment: Make it all one form.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't make all one form

Comment: And why would that be?

Comment: I would be curious to hear why you cannot make it one form as well.

Comment: Any reason you aren't using jQuery ajax to $.post() and then using the success(), error() or done() functions? What is the purpose? What is being posted? What is being returned? is this used for "serial" file uploads? If so, there are better jQuery plugins than attempting to roll your own... like dropzonejs or jQuery-File-Upload if you need chunking support for large video files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the source of the action page put a script that submits the next form. You'll have to:

- use `top` or `parent` in the action's script
- keep track of the iteration by putting a hidden field in each form
- add the 'name' attribute to each form with the iteration, such as 'myForm4'

So when the hidden field `iteration=4` is passed from the 4th form, you output in a script:

```
top.document.myForm4.submit();
```